# nodejs pass value from controller to view

Tags: node.js, pug

```
res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
```

Above line just means index.jade (view) can use the `#{title}` which will get '`Express`'.

Does `res.locals.title = 'Express'` do the samething? What's the different between those two?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Both do same thing, But there is small difference.

res.locals scoped to the request, and therefore available only to the view(s) rendered during that request / response cycle (if any).

They'll be 'global' in the render, so you don't need to prep-end anything on to them to use them.
This property is useful for exposing request-level information such as the request path name, authenticated user, user settings, and so on.

```
//Example, It will attach user info with every response.
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  res.locals.user = req.user;
  next();
});
```

in res.render(view [, locals] [, callback])
locals is an object whose properties define local variables for that view only.

Comment: so the later one is better, coz it doesn't `leak` it to global?